# "An error has occured" when opening a bot on Azure bot service

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have developed a bot directly online on Azure bot service during the free trial.
Now the trial is expired and I would like to download my code as depicted here (from the documentation):

[image]

But I actually cannot even access this page anymore.

When I click on my bot:

[image]

I directly go to blank page (but still with the black surrounding and icons) with this error:

[image]

I don't think it is a deployment problem because I've never deployed it from outside. All has been coded from the webapp.

Comment: [As the docs say](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/) _"The $200 credit expires after 30 days, and you can either let any services you’ve deployed be decommissioned **(and you won’t have access to them anymore)** or transition to a Pay-As-You-Go Azure subscription, paying only for what you use moving forward."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try accessing your bot via kudu? To do so, visit https://your-bot-name.scm.azurewebsites.net

If you can, select CMD from the Debug console menu on the top, and then navigate to "site". Finally download the whole wwwroot folder.

It might not work, because your subscription has expired, but worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately I have a 403 when doing this.

Comment: @EmmanuelHadoux, I'm afraid you can't then. The [Azure trial FAQ](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/) says "_What happens with the services I created after 30 days?
The $200 credit expires after 30 days, and you can either let any services you’ve deployed be decommissioned (and you won’t have access to them anymore) or transition to a Pay-As-You-Go Azure subscription, paying only for what you use moving forward._".

Answer (score 0):

There was a temporary issue with Bot Service bots last month (those created in the Azure Portal).  It has since been fixed.  However, if you created your bot during the time the issue was in place: the portal can become disconnected from the code. Here is how you can retrieve it:

Please download the **Azure Storage Explorer** from here: http://storageexplorer.com/

Login, and navigate to your resource group's Storage Account. When you open it, you'll see File Shares. There you'll find the source for your bot.

[image: Storage Explorer Image]

You could also access the source files via Kudu console: http://dotnetthoughts.net/using-kudu-with-microsoft-azure-web-apps/

Comment: Your solution is the one with which I can go the furthest however, under "File Shares" I have a "Load More" link. When I click on it a popup comes up with "Could not obtain keys for Storage Account. Please check that you have the correct permissions."

Comment: This must be because your trial has expired.